# Facebook App On Mobile - View Notification - "Privacy check failed - You can not see that"

Tags: facebook, privacy

We've just developed a Facebook application which has a piece of functionality that allows you to post to a friends' wall. Fairly simple piece of functionality, and it's been working so far on the main www.facebook.com website. If I receive a notification that someone has posted on my timeline, and can click the link, and see the post. This is fine.

However, move to the iPhone app, or the mobile website, and it's not the same. I see the notification, click the link, and then see the following Facebook error message:

Privacy Check Failed
You can not see that.

Interestingly, in the mobile website, if I simply change the subdomain part of the URL in the address bar from

https://**m**.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=XXX&id=XXX

to

https://**www**.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=XXX&id=XXX

To access the full site, it works fine, and I can see the post (I've blanked the IDs for privacy).

After some research on the web, I can't anyone who has recently seen this message. Has anyone else seen it before? My instinct is telling me it's a bug with Facebook, but I want to check I'm not missing anything.